Is a finitely generated module over a hereditary ring always finitely presented? When does $Ext^{n}( M, -)$, for $n \geq 0$, commute with direct sum?
In the §6 Appendix II (2) of the article  Gorenstein projective modules says that:
Lemma 1 : Let $R$ be a ring. If $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then
$$Ext^{n}( M, \oplus_{i\in I}\ N_{i}) \cong \oplus_{i\in I}\ Ext^{n}(M, N_{i}),\ n \geq 0 .$$
I seriously doubt the correctness of Lemma 1. This is because Corollary 2.5 in the article  Modules $M$ such that $Ext^{1}_{R}(M,−)$ Commutes
with Direct Limits states that:
Corollary 2.5 Let $R$ be an right hereditary ring and $M$ a right R-module. The following are equivalent:
(1) $Ext^{1}_{R}(M,−)$ commutes with direct limits;
(2) $Ext^{1}_{R}(M,−)$ commutes with direct sums;
(3) $Ext^{1}_{R}(M,−)$ commutes with direct sums of copies of R;
(4) $M=N⊕P$, where $N$ is finitely presented and $P$ is projective.
If there exists a finitely generated module $M$ over a right hereditary ring $R$ such that $M$ is not finitely presented, then by the equivalence between (2) and (4) in Corollary 2.5, it follows that $Ext^{1}_{R}(M,−)$ does not commute with direct sums. Given such a situation, we can deduce the incorrectness of Lemma 1 previously mentioned.
Therefore, the following questions naturally arise:
(1)Is a finitely generated module over a hereditary ring always finitely presented?
(2)As is well known, if $M$ admits a resolution by finitely generated projectives, then $$Ext^{n}( M, \oplus_{i\in I}\ N_{i}) \cong \oplus_{i\in I}\ Ext^{n}(M, N_{i}),\ n \geq 0 .$$
Given that $M$ admits a resolution by finitely generated projectives is a sufficient condition, are there any other sufficient conditions? Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for this equation to be an isomorphism?

Maybe this helps: If I remember correctly the property you are asking for is that of a compact object in your derived category. These are often the perfect complexes, which in particular for the case of a heredetary algebra is essentially the finitely presented ones.

Thank you! Your response was very helpful.

To answer (1):
No, that's not true. Note that if all finitely generated modules are finitely presented, then the base ring is Noetherian (proof: take an ideal $I$ and consider $R/I$), so a counterexample is just a non-Noetherian hereditary ring. One can take $k\langle x,y\rangle$, the free algebra in two variables over a field.
To address (2):
Due to implicit qualifiers, there are a couple of different ways to interpret the question. But note that the case $n=0$ is already interesting. You're asking for conditions for when, among other things, the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,-)$ preserves direct sums. You can find some discussion of that (sub)question here.

Your hint is very useful. Thank you!

A non-Noetherian Prüfer domain is semihereditary but not hereditary. So, to look for non-Noetherian hereditary rings, one must consider rings that are not domains.

@GeoffreyTrang thank you for your comment, you're right. I have edited in an actual example of a non-Noetherian hereditary ring.
